# Rock Paper Scissors game issue

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I built a very basic rock paper scissors game but it seems that somehow the game is not correctly capturing the userSelection or outputing the correct result...

I've spent hours researching and adjusting various aspects of my code but can't figure it out - I'm too green I guess.

I don't want a totally different version of how to do this -I'd like to fix this version and understand why it doesn't work currently :)

https://codepen.io/anna_whiskey/pen/XWRjQXV

```
    const gameInputs = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    let computerSel;
    let round1Answer;
    let userSelection;


    
    function game() {
    function humanPlay() {

      document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", () => {
                userSelection = "rock";
            
            })
      document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", () => {
                userSelection = "paper";
                
            })
      document.getElementById("btn3").addEventListener("click", () => {
                userSelection = "scissors";
                
            })
            
        }

        

        function computerPlay() {
            computerSel = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameInputs.length);
            round1Answer = (gameInputs[computerSel]);
            console.log((gameInputs[computerSel]));
            humanPlay();
        }
        computerPlay();

        document.getElementById("outcome").textContent = `You: ${userSelection} Computer: ${round1Answer}`

        function playRound(round1Answer, userSelection) {

            if (userSelection === 'rock' && round1Answer === 'scissors') {
                alert('You WIN!');
            } else if (userSelection === 'rock' && round1Answer === 'rock') {
                alert('It/s a tie!');
            } else if (userSelection === 'paper' && round1Answer === 'rock') {
                alert('You WIN!');
            } else if (userSelection === 'paper' && round1Answer === 'paper') {
                alert('It/s a tie!');
            } else if (userSelection === 'scissors' && round1Answer === 'paper') {
                alert('You WIN!');
            } else if (userSelection === 'scissors' && round1Answer === 'scissors') {
                alert('It/s a tie!');
            } else {
                alert('You LOSE!');
            }
        }
        playRound(round1Answer, userSelection);
    } 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
<body>
<div class="bg"></div>


<button id="btn1" onclick="game()">Rock</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="game()">Paper</button>
<button id="btn3" onclick="game()">Scissors</button>

<div id="outcome"></div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="rps.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="rpsv2.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if any property for Node named clicked. `document.getElementById("btn1").clicked` this is not a valid syntax. Btw install of comparing `document.getElementById("btn1").clicked = true` in this line you are assigning a new property for this node to `true` so every time first condition become truthy , that why you are getting the rock every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try adding event listeners for human inputs

```js
const gameInputs = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
let computerSel;
let round1Answer;
let userSelection;


function game() {

    function humanPlay() {

        document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", () => {
            userSelection = "rock";
            console.log(`User Selection: ${userSelection}`)
        })
        document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", () => {
            userSelection = "paper";
            console.log(`User Selection: ${userSelection}`)
        })
        document.getElementById("btn3").addEventListener("click", () => {
            userSelection = "scissor";
            console.log(`User Selection: ${userSelection}`)
        })
    }

    function computerPlay() {

        computerSel = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        round1Answer = (gameInputs[computerSel]);
        // console.log(`Round ans is ${round1Answer}`)

    }

    function playRound(round1Answer, userSelection) {

        if (userSelection == 'rock' && round1Answer == 'scissors') {
            alert('You WIN!');
        } 
        else if (userSelection == 'paper' && round1Answer == 'rock') {
            alert('You WIN!');
        } 
        else if (userSelection == 'scissors' && round1Answer == 'paper') {
            alert('You WIN!');
        } 
        else if (userSelection == 'rock' && round1Answer == 'rock') {
            alert('It/s a tie!');
        } 
        else if (userSelection == 'paper' && round1Answer == 'paper') {
            alert('It/s a tie!');
        } 
        else if (userSelection == 'scissors' && round1Answer == 'scissors') {
            alert('It/s a tie!');
        } 
        else {
            alert('You LOSE!');
        }
    }
    humanPlay();
    computerPlay();
    playRound(round1Answer, userSelection);
}
```

using this i managed to log rock paper and scissor

Comment: Thank you Om!  I can't get this code to run for me for some reason - are you sure it works for you?

Comment: https://codepen.io/avicdr/pen/eYWdwYm check if it works

Comment: Ah ok amazing it works now thank you!! (my html was wrong..) - BUT it doesn't log userSelection to the console, do you know why?

Comment: it dosen't logs for the very first attempt

Comment: it'll start logging from the second click

Comment: Oh got it!  But now I realized the logic isn't working for some reason - if the user clicks on "rock" for example, and the computer chooses "scissors" - it should tell the user "You Win" but it doesn't....it says "You lose" or it's a tie but it's always wrong....

Comment: it's totally fine because nobody's gonna find what the comp's choosing

Comment: I tried, it doesn't let me upvote yet because I don't have enough points myself yet...sorry ....   I need to make it work properly otherwise it's pointless...@BinRohan do you know why the above code works but doesn't make the correct choice when it comes to the alert?

Comment: umm can you give me some time i'll make the computer choice selection work too 

Comment: i would like to mention that your html was very disordered as some tags even did not had closing tags

Comment: Ok thanks!  It seems it is only incorrect the FIRST time a button is clicked for some reason....after that it works....

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't output the correct "win/lose/tie"... :(

Comment: kk i'll see into it

Comment: https://codepen.io/avicdr/pen/eYWdwYm Checkout the updated codepen 

Comment: also i tried to log computerSelection it showed the correct result according to the userChoice

Comment: No problems, happy to help you 

Comment: Also I just added some styling else just three buttons were too odd

Comment: it just shows wrong answer on the very first attemp after that the results are accurate

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do the task by the following script
**JS**

```
const gameInputs = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
let computerSel;
let round1Answer;
let userSelection;


function game (humanChoosed) {
  
  userSelection = gameInputs[humanChoosed];

  function computerPlay() {
    computerSel = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameInputs.length);
    round1Answer = (gameInputs[computerSel]);
  }
computerPlay();

  document.querySelector('h1').textContent = `Human: ${userSelection} Computer: ${round1Answer}`;

  function playRound (round1Answer, userSelection) {
 
    if (userSelection === 'rock' && round1Answer === 'scissors') {
        alert ('You WIN!');
    } else if (userSelection === 'rock' && round1Answer === 'rock') {
        alert ('It/s a tie!');
    } else if (userSelection === 'paper' && round1Answer === 'rock') {
        alert ('You WIN!');
    } else if (userSelection === 'paper' && round1Answer === 'paper') {
        alert ('It/s a tie!');
    } else if (userSelection === 'scissors' && round1Answer === 'paper') {
        alert ('You WIN!');
    } else if (userSelection === 'scissors' && round1Answer === 'scissors') {
        alert ('It/s a tie!');
    } else {
       alert ('You LOSE!');
    }
  } 
  playRound (round1Answer, userSelection);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="bg"></div>

  <button id="btn1" onclick="game(0)">Rock</button> 
  <button id="btn2" onclick="game(1)">Paper</button>  
  <button id="btn3" onclick="game(2)">Scissors</button> 

  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="rps.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rps.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bin Rohan - this works, but I'd love to still understand why my version does not work (or how to make it work if possible) :)

Comment: ALSO - I don't understand how the computer is figuring out which button the user chooses in your example above??

Comment: Those buttons calling the function `game()` and passes the index number respect to your this array `const gameInputs = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];`. Then in your `game` function it is retrieving the value for the given index, from this line `userSelection = gameInputs[humanChoosed];`.

Comment: @Anna-Delta, answer to your first comment, First of all there is nothing link this `document.getElementById("btn1").clicked ` in JS . Second, in this line `document.getElementById("btn1").clicked = true` you are creating new property clicked and assigning `true` as a value.

Comment: If you want similar to your solution then the best you can do:
`if (document.getElementById("btn1").textContent.toLowerCase() === 'rock') {
        userSelection = 'rock';
        console.log(userSelection);
    }`